# how to not get empty array in swift playground?

Tags: ios, swift, api, get, nsurlsession

I'm getting response from API's but I am not able to get emails array back, what am I doing wrong?
I tried to add DispatchQueue.main.asyn { emails.append(result.data.email) } but its the same result.

```
// MARK: - Response Class
struct Response: Codable {
    let data: DataClass
    let support: Support
}

// MARK: - DataClass
struct DataClass: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let email, firstName, lastName: String
    let avatar: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, email
        case firstName = "first_name"
        case lastName = "last_name"
        case avatar
    }
}

// MARK: - Support
struct Support: Codable {
    let url: String
    let text: String
}

let urls = [
    URL(string: "https://reqres.in/api/users/1"),
    URL(string: "https://reqres.in/api/users/3"),
    URL(string: "https://reqres.in/api/users/10")
]


func getEmailFromAPI(urls: [URL?]) -> [String] {
    var emails: [String] = []
    for url in urls {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URLRequest(url: url!)) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            guard let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data) else { return }
            print(result.data.email)
            emails.append(result.data.email)
        }.resume()
    }
    return emails
}

print(getEmailFromAPI(urls: urls))
```

Please advice as to what am I doing wrong, Thanks.

Comment: You have asynchronous code (inside data task handler) that you are expecting to behave synchronously. The newest fix is to switch to `async await` it is the "better" option but you should to research on completion handlers.

Comment: It's the asynchronous concept your are missing. Replace `print(result.data.email)` with `print("Inside closure: \(result.data.email)')`, and `return emails` with `print("outside closure: \(emails)"); return emails` . Which one did you expect to be printed first?

Answer (score 0):

> "return emails" statement will get executed before your array gets loaded with data because of the async operation.

So you can use closure to pass the emails as per below

```
func getEmailFromAPI(urls: [URL?], emailResult: @escaping ([String]?) -> Void) {
        var emails: [String] = []
        for url in urls {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URLRequest(url: url!)) { data, response, error in
                if error != nil {
                    emailResult(nil)
                }else {
                    guard let data = data else { return }
                    print(result.data.email)
                    emails.append(result.data.email)
                    emailResult(emails)
                }
            }.resume()
        }
    }
```

**Suggestion** - prefer to not append email operation instead create a codable object for the same